# Copying values from one array to another

Tags: c, arrays, debugging

It should be simple,two arrays,one with 5 other with 6 elements.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int k=0;
    int v[5] = {2,3,4,5,6};
    int g[6];

    for( i = 1; i <= 6; i++ ){
        k= i + 1;
        if ( 1 == i && 2 == i)
        {
            g[k]=v[i];
        }
        else
        {
            g[k]=(v[i]+10);
        }

        printf("%d\n",g[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I got this

```
13
14
15
16
32776
10
```

I really wanted

```
2 3 13 14 15 16
```

Where is my mistake?Should I create function or what?

Comment: You go to 6th element in `i` loop when there are only indexes 0-5 available in either of your arrays.

Comment: The control always goes to the else block. I cannot be 2 and 1 at the same time.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: you mean the 7th and 0-4?

Comment: can you explain what you are attempting to do with this program besides just say I have 2 arrays, what are you actually trying to make happen? I can already tell that `32776` being printed out is a mistake in the for loop somewhere and it is just printing a garbage value. also you are checking i against 1 and 2 and using && which isnt possible

Comment: You might want to check `if (1==i && 2==i)`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, that as well.

Comment: Seriously though, just print out your indexes to the console every loop and you'll see where you've gone out of bounds.

Comment: 'if ( 1 == i && 2 == i)' this will be always false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Problem 1

Array indexes are 0-based, meaning `v[0]` and `g[0]` are the first element of the arrays. All your `i` and `k` are off by one 1.

### Problem 2

`1 == i && 2 == i` is never true. If `1 == i`, then `2 != i`. If `2 == i`, then `1 != i`.

```
1 == i && 2 == i
```

should be

```
1 == i || 2 == i
```

### Problem 3

Your loop has 5 passes, but it requires 6!

```
1) g[0] = v[0];
2) g[1] = v[1];
3) g[2] = v[1]+10;
4) g[3] = v[2]+10;
5) g[4] = v[3]+10;
6) g[5] = v[4]+10;
```

### Solution

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int v[5] = {2,3,4,5,6};
    int g[6];

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(g)/sizeof(*g); ++i ) {
        if ( 0 == i || 1 == i )
           g[i] = v[i];
        else
           g[i] = v[i-1]+10;

        printf("%d\n", g[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that

```
if ( 0 == i || 1 == i )
```

can be simplified to

```
if ( 2 < i )
```

Comment: This fixes one issue, but still reads off the end of the arrays.

Comment: Again, not quite.  User wants 2,3,13,14,15,16 - gotta take one off the index as above.

Comment: Yours is the "answer" now, so time to fix it :)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your code has a few problems:

- `if ( 1 == i && 2 == i)` will always return `false` as a variable cannot be both 1 and 2 at the same time.
- Your loop iterator takes values larger than they should; when `i` becomes `5` and `6`, `v[i]` and `g[i]` triggers reads to memory locations beyond the respective arrays' memory ranges, which explains the random values in your output.

I think this is what you want:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int v[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int g[6];

    for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
    {
        if ( i < 2 )
        {
            g[i] = v[i];
        }

        else
        {
            g[i] = ( v[i - 1] + 10 );
        }

        printf ( "%d\n", g[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 13 14 15 16
```

Comment: You should mention them again. Answers are supposed to stand on their own, comments are considered ephemeral.

Comment: BTW, congrats on getting the correct answer first.  190k karma is beating you up at the moment is all.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Haha! That's okay! I'm glad that the OP got his question's answer, one way or the other. As a consolation, I got a lot of upvotes, so yay!

Answer (score 1):

It never enter in the **if** conditional block because i cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time.. 
So your code will enter just in else...
and it wil start from index 1;

 so in this expresion from else : `g[k]=(v[i]+10);` --- `v[i]=> 3` and when you arrive at index 5 or 6 it is outside of your v array....

```
for( i = 1; i <= 6; i++ ){
        k= i + 1;
        if ( 1 == i && 2 == i) //never enter here...
        {
            g[k]=v[i];
        }
        else
        {
            g[k]=(v[i]+10); //index get outside the vector length
        }

        printf("%d\n",g[k]);
    }
```